# Convergence of type $1/(kn+r)$ type series

Tags: integration

Find a necessary and sufficient condition on $A$, $B$, and $C$ for which the series converges and find the sum in case of convergent.
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac A{5n+1}+\frac B{5n+2}+\frac C{5n+3}$$
I found $A + B + C = 0$. Is that right?

Comment: Can you show more of your works?

Comment: That is correct. To me the easiest way is to bring the expression to a common denominator (we do not have to write out all the terms of the numerator).

Comment: Nice question! (+1) Combining three divergent to make one convergent series in such a simple yet interesting fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\forall n\ge1 \wedge \forall 1\leq j \leq 3$
$$\frac{1}{5n+j}=\frac{1}{5n}-\frac{j}{5n(5n+j)}=\frac{1}{5n}+O(\frac{1}{n^2})$$

So that we have, $\forall n\ge1$

$$\frac{A}{5n+1}+\frac{B}{5n+2}+\frac{C}{5n+3}=\frac{(A+B+C)}{5}\frac{1}{n}+O(\frac{1}{n^2})$$

So clearly we must have $A+B+C=0$ in order for your series to converge.